# Compute the damping value for two masses in a harmonic oscillator

Tags: mass, harmonic-oscillator, spring, vibrations

Consider that this is a simple mass spring damper system:

$$ \ m \frac{d^{2}x}{dt} = F - b\frac{dx}{dt} - kx\ $$

[image]

What I allready know is the force $ F $ and the mass $ m $. Then I can find the spring stiffness k by sett all the derivatives to zero.

Then I can compute the damper $ b $ throught this formula:
$$ \ b = \zeta 2 \sqrt{k m}\ $$

According to Wikipedia, the damping ratio $ \zeta = 0.7 \ $ is a good number.

And this really works too! I have test it by my own ODE simulations, and it works OK! Perfect!

But the question is:
If I have two or more ODE:s with diffrent spring stiffness and dampness like this:
$$ \ m_{2}\frac{d^{2}z}{dt} = F - C_{2}(\frac{dz}{dt} - \frac{dy}{dt}) - k_{2}(z - y) \\ m_{1}\frac{d^{2}y}{dt} = C_{2}(\frac{dz}{dt} - \frac{dy}{dt}) + k_{2}(z - y) - C_1\frac{dy}{dt} - k_1 y\  $$

I can compute the stiffness $ k_1 , k_2 $ if I know the masses $ m_1 , m_2 $ and the force $ F $ , and also I need to set some position values for $ y , z $

Very easy! But how do I compute the damper $ C_1 , C_2 $ if I determine that $ \zeta = 0.7 $ ?

[image]

Comment: You might have better luck parametrizing the 1DOF problem with $$\matrix{k = m \omega^2_n & c = 2 \zeta m \omega_n}$$ where $\omega_n^2 = \frac{k}{m}$. So now the damping is _proportional_ to the undamped natural frequency $\omega_n$. In would be reasonable to assume that for 2DOF systems damping should scale with nat. freq. also.

Comment: @ja72 Please, can you show me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to tackle a special case of the general problem stated in the question. I hope this would leads to some insight into how to handle the general problem.

Consider the 2-DOF system, but with each mass equal to $m_1=m_2 =\frac{m}{2}$ (so the total mass is $m$), each stiffness $k_1=k_2 = 2 k$ (so the combined stiffness is $k$) and each damping is $c_1=c_2 =2 c$ for the same reason.

To solve the problem, I formulated the equations of motion in terms of the absolute displacements $x_1$ and $x_2$, but then I switched the DOF of the system to relative displacements $ q_1 = x_1 $ and $q_2 = x_2-x_1$.

As a system of equations this is

$$ \pmatrix{\ddot{q}_1 \\ \ddot{q}_2 } + \left[ \matrix{ \frac{4 k}{m} & -\frac{4 k}{m} \\ -\frac{4 k}{m} & \frac{8 k}{m} } \right] \pmatrix{q_1 \\ q_2} + \left[ \matrix{ \frac{4 c}{m} & -\frac{4 c}{m} \\ -\frac{4 c}{m} & \frac{8 c}{m} } \right] \pmatrix{\dot{q}_1 \\ \dot{q}_2}= \pmatrix{0\\0} $$

This system has an "in-phase" solution of

$$\pmatrix{q_1  \\ q_2 } = \pmatrix{Q_1 \\ Q_2} \exp(-\beta t) \sin(\omega t) $$

Since this is a 2-DOF system it has two natural frequencies

$$ \omega_n^2 = \begin{cases} 
  \frac{2 k( 3-\sqrt{5})}{m} & \mbox{mode A} \\
  \frac{2 k( 3+\sqrt{5})}{m} & \mbox{mode B} \end{cases} $$

These are found from the *eigenvalues* of the 2×2 matrix multiplying $\pmatrix{q_1 & q_2}$ in the equations of motion.

The values of $\beta$ and $\omega$ that solve the system are 
$$\begin{aligned}
  \beta & = \frac{c\, \omega_n^2}{2 k} \\
  \omega^2 & = \omega_n^2 \left(1- \frac{c^2\, \omega_n^2}{4 k^2} \right)
\end{aligned} $$

Using the values of $\beta$ and $\omega$ that solve the system of equations, one can parametrise them as $$ \begin{aligned} \beta & = \omega_n \zeta \\ \omega & = \omega_n \sqrt{1-\zeta^2} \end{aligned}$$ which is exactly what you do in the 1-DOF system. This means that the stiffness $k$ and damping $c$ needed for a response with natural frequency $\omega_n$ and damping ratio $\zeta$ are

$$\boxed{ \begin{aligned}
  k & = \frac{m \, \omega_n^2}{2 (3 \pm \sqrt{5})} \\
  c & = \frac{m \, \omega_n \zeta}{(3 \pm \sqrt{5})} 
\end{aligned} }$$

Also note that to target a specific *half-life* of $t_H$ where $\exp(-\beta t_H) = \frac{1}{2}$ you need a damping ratio of $\zeta = \frac{ \ln(2)}{\omega_n\, t_H}$.

Finally, for completeness I am going to mention that the response amplitudes are arbitrary, but must be related to each with $Q_2 = -Q_1 \frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

Comment: The insight here is that the displacement $x_2$  exhibits two harmonic responses, the relative displacement $q_2$ has only one harmonic response and can be solved with _one simple sine function_ as opposed to a superposition of two sine waves for $x_2$.

Comment: Good! What if $m_1 \neq m_2$ and $k_1 \neq k_2$ and $c_1 \neq c_2$ ? It cannot be solved, right?

Comment: I think it is also solvable, just the equations are a bit more complex. Once the eigenvalues are found and $\omega_n$ is set, then $k$ can be directly defined from $\omega_n$. Finally, the solution would yield the values of $c$ and $Q_2/Q_1$.

Answer (score 0):

In the general case there is no simple answer to this, because the vibration modes of the damped system are different from the undamped system. Even worse, the modes of the damped system may be complex - i.e. different degrees of freedom do not move in phase with each other.

But for your specific model, those problems don't apply. First write the equations in matrix form:
$$M \ddot x + C \dot x + Kx = F$$
where
$$\begin{align}
M &= \begin{bmatrix}m_1 & 0 \\ 0 & m_2 \end{bmatrix} \\[6pt]
C &= \begin{bmatrix}c_1 + c_2 & -c_2 \\ -c_2 & c_2 \end{bmatrix} \\[6pt]
K &= \begin{bmatrix}k_1 + k_2 & -k_2 \\ -k_2 & k_2 \end{bmatrix} \\[6pt]
x &= \begin{bmatrix}y \\ z \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}$$

For any values of the $m$'s, $c$'s, and $k$'s, we can express $C$ as a linear combination of $M$ and $K$, i.e. $C = \alpha M + \beta K$ for some constants $\alpha$ and $\beta$. This property of $C$ is known as *Rayleigh damping* and has the nice consequence that the mode shapes of the damped and undamped systems are identical.

So, you can solve your problem as follows:

- Find the modes of the undamped system $M\ddot x + Kx = F$
- Set the damping factors for each mode to your preferred value
- Find the damping matrix $C$
- Identify the physical coefficients $c_1$ and $c_2$.

There is a potential problem with this: you might find that $c_1 < 0$ which is not physically meaningful. But that is most likely to happen if you try to make the damping ratios for the two modes very different from each other, and apparently you don't want to do that.

Google will find plenty of references to Rayleigh damping, and it should be covered in a good dynamics textbook in the section on multi-degree-of-freedom (MDOF) systems.

In fact you don't need to go through all the steps I described above: from the general theory of Rayleigh damping, you can find the constants $\alpha$ and $\beta$ directly from the modal frequencies of the undamped system, and then get $c_1$ and $c_2$ directly. (But writing out all the theory behind that is more work than I'm prepared to do right now!)

Comment: Wow! Thanks! I will look up more of the Rayleigh damping! By the way! Do you think that I can use eigenvalues to determine the damping values? The more negative eigenvalues it is, the more faster the system will be. Just a teory i just got.

Comment: It would be great if you can show me how to solve c1, c2 if i know k1, k2, m1, m2 and F.

Comment: If you transform the equations into modal coordinates, the mass and stiffness matrices are then diagonal. Suppose the diagonal entries for the mass matrix are $m^*_1$, $m^*_2,$ and similarly for the stiffness and damping matrices. You then calculate the diagonal damping matrix. to get the damping ratios you want. Then find $\alpha$ and $\beta$ by solving the simultaneous equation $c^*_1 = \alpha m^*_1 + \beta k^*_1$ and $c^*_2 = \alpha m^*_2 + \beta k^*_2$. Then go back to the matrices in physical coordinates to find $c_1$ and $c_2$.

Comment: Sorry! Do not understand.

Comment: By the way! Can I not choose good eigenvalues for the system and then compute the damping after choosen eigen value? Let say i choose -3 for eigenvalues for all z and y position? The more negative eigenvalue it is, the faster will the system be, but it will then be a over shoot. Is this possible? I'm only intrested to find the damping value so the position amplitude for z och y is the same. Here is my MATLAB/Octave code. https://pastebin.com/cJap0RGY