# How to determine the critical damping factors for a multi-DOF mass-spring system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction, spring, coupled-oscillators

How do I choose $ b_1 $, $ b_2 $ and $b_3$ to make the masses $m_1$, $m_2$ and $m_3$ have a critical damping behavior? If I have just one mass $m$ and one spring $k$ and one damper $b$, the damper would have the value $$ b = 2*\sqrt{m*k} $$

to give the mass a critically damping behaviour. But now I have a system of ODEs. The stiffness is very easy to determine because as the developer I can choose the static equilibrium point. My picture (and accompanying equations) below will explain.

> **System of ODE on second order:**
>   $$m_3*ddh = m_3g - k_3(h-y)-b_3(dh-dy)$$
>   $$m_2*ddy = m_2*g +k_3(h-y)+b_3(dh-dy)-k_2(y-z)-b_2(dy-dz)$$
>   $$m_1*ddz = m_1*g + k_2(y-z)+b_2(dy-dz)-k_1*z-b_1*dz$$
>
> **Determine the stiffness if $h$, $y$, and $z$ are known: $h>y>z$**
>   $$k_3 = \frac{m_3*g}{h-y}$$
>   $$k_2 = \frac{m_3*g+m_2*g}{y-z}$$
>   $$k_1 = \frac{m_3*g+m_2*g+m_1*g}{z}$$
>
> [image]

Comment: Related : [Compute the damping value for two masses in a harmonic oscillator](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/335983)

Comment: How? I can do that with one mass. But I don't know how to do that if there are multiple masses in the system.

Comment: Exactly. Your related question (answered by Alephzero) says you can do it for one mass, then asks "But the question is: If I have two or more ODE:s with diffrent spring stiffness and dampness ...". You seem to be asking the same question multiple times : eg [Get the damping coefficient if I know the natural frequency - MDOF](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/336715)

Comment: I assume that is not possible to get critical damping for a MDOF system.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is a 'trick' question since critical damping is strictly defined for a second order (2 state ) linear dynamic system. Your diagram results in a 6th order system. And while you might consider separately solving each platform independently, as they are 2nd order subsystems, the subsystems 'couple' and so do the damping factors.

One may be able to solve a linear transfer function for the 6th order system and use model reduction techniques to acquire an appropriate 2nd order model, but a faster, simpler approach would be to simulate the system, and 'tune' your three factors by trial and error so that the response of the 6th order system approaches what appears closest to critical damping.

If the simulation tool has optimization functions,  like Vissim,  you can automatically determine a set of parameters such that your system approaches a second order critical damped response of a reference model. Maybe 30 min and you have an answer.

Comment: So you mean, simulate with MATLAB (or other software) and try diffrent values for $b1$, $b2$ and $b3$ so the system will act as the behaviour I want it to do, will solve my problem, even if it's not and an exactly solution for the system? I have heard many diffrent ways to solve a damping matrix, but thoose way seems to be quite hard to apply.

Comment: Critical damping precisely defined, and although you may be able to achieve in the independent 2nd order subsystems of your system, coupling will lead to damping other than critical. Critical damping simply not defined for higher than 2nd order systems

Comment: Matlab,  simulink, vissim, yes. There is no exact solution since your system,  6th order. Critical damping is not defined.

Comment: You can however get close to the response of a second order critically damped system

Comment: Thanks! If critical damping is not defined for MDOF-system, I will no longer think about to solve it on exact form. I going to simulate this with ODE45 from Octave. It's a free "version" of MATLAB. By the way! This is the "many diffrent ways" I was talking about https://donkey2ft.files.wordpress.com/2014/03/damping-matrix.pdf I was trying to do the "Proposed damping matrix"-method, but it did not work beacuse I have to add in and remove dampers that should not exist. Just to make the C damping matrix fit my system.

Comment: I disagree with most of the answer and the answerer's comments. Ignoring the damping, this is a system with three normal modes. There is no problem in defining damping factors for each mode, and making them all "critical" (i.e. equal to 1). However the resulting damping matrix will probably *not* be realizable by the three dampers show in the OP's diagram. If the OP wants an "approximate" solution using only the three dampers shown, the first step is for *the OP* to define what criterion to use to find the "best" approximation.

Comment: If there is not problem to defining damping factors for the system. Can you show med then how to do? I don't need all the dampers to be placed as the diagram. Please, show med how to computer the best damping values.

Comment: Okey! Nobody have a answer for this question. I think the real answer is: There is no exact form for the damping. You have to simulate the ODE system and try some diffrent values and feel what values of $b1$, $b2$ and $b3$ will give a critical damping. The real answer I guess? Thank you, anyway!

Comment: That's right. But as you can see others strongly disagree with my answer, punished me with downvotes. Sigh.

Comment: Okej! But I belive you beacuse the others have not show a exact solution for this problem. Thanks to Octave with ode23s, I have now solve this problem! By the way! I saw that you are a control engineer. Me too! I love LQG controllers!  I'm going to build one with analog electrical components. PID controllers are so boring beacuse they are too easy. Multivariable and optimal controllers with embedded fiter is the future.